# How to maintain all element's independent height of interactjs removeable element?

Tags: javascript, interact.js

using dragabled and resizeable element, when resizing one, it causing children element height will be auto changed,
like this gif says: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfGVj.gif)
[image]

I only want change the resize element,
maintain the children elements's height not been changed. 
How can I to config interactjs?

[online jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/askie/660cgLpd/4/)

```
660cgLpd
```